# How to fix add to cart functionality in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building an ecommerce platform and I want to create the add to cart functionality in the website. But for some reason the Product Id is showing null.
Here's the codes:
**models.py**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    product_category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField(max_length= 5)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_cart(request):
    product_id = Products.id
    new_product = Cart.objects.get_or_create(id=product_id, user=request.user)
    return redirect('/')
```

**templates**

```
<div class="product-wrapper">
      <h1 style="font-size:24px">{{product.title}}</h1>
      <div class="product-price">
        <p style="text-decoration-line:line-through;">$ {{product.price}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'add-product' product.product_id %}">Add to cart<a>
          </div>
```

When I try to click this link it gives me this error: **Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002468A4F8550>.**
Any suggestion will be really helpful.
 Thank you

Comment: `product_id = Products.id` makes no sense: you should submit the id through the URL, or through POST parameters.

Comment: I tried to submit it through another method but it doesn't work that way too.

Comment: Share the form that makes the request.

Comment: I have added the template that is making the request. This is a detailview page and not in a for loop.

Comment: and the `urls.py`. It seems like you use another view than `add_cart`.

Comment: I've fixed it already. And thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've fixed this.
**view.py**

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    products = Products.objects.get(slug=slug)
    ncart = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user, products=products)
    ncart.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

**template**

```
<div class="product-wrapper">
      <h1 style="font-size:24px">{{product.title}}</h1>
      <div class="product-price">
        <p style="text-decoration-line:line-through;">$ {{product.price}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}">Add to cart<a>
          </div>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('cart/add/<slug:slug>', views.add_to_cart, name = 'add-to-cart')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you've got Products instance already, in that case

Query directly like:

```
new_product = Cart.objects.get_or_create(products=Products)
```

If you want to query from the product_id, do it like that:

```
product_id = Products.pk
new_product = Cart.objects.get_or_create(products_id=product_id)
```

In addition:
request.user contains a dictionary, you can't pass it directly to query. And the user field has name buyer, so change that query like that:

```
product_id = Products.pk
new_product = Cart.objects.get_or_create(products=Products, buyer_id=request.user['pk'])
```

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got <property object at 0x000001A97EB06130>.
I get the same erros using this method too

Comment: remove id from the filters. Add the field name directly as shown in the answer.